# Take previous hour data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hai guys i want to take previous hour data in SQL.

I have found something like this

```
DATEPART(hh,GETDATE())-1 –>
```

But it has some issues, since my date format is 24hr. It will give -ve value (-1) when the time is between 00.00.00-00.59.59 . I should get 23 as value. Any suggestions? This is what i did

```
DECLARE @hourlyaggregatedvolume smallint
DECLARE @hourlyaggregatedspeed smallint
DECLARE @hourlyaggregatedoccupancy float
DECLARE @hourlyaggregatedheadway float 
DECLARE @trafficdatadate datetime   
DECLARE @closeststationname nvarchar(100) = 'E100 1001'
DECLARE @accidentdate nvarchar(10) = '2014-02-17'
DECLARE @accidenttime nvarchar(10) = '01:10:00'
  SELECT 
           @hourlyaggregatedvolume = aggregated_volume,
           @hourlyaggregatedspeed  =aggregated_speed,
           @hourlyaggregatedheadway = aggregated_headway,
           @hourlyaggregatedoccupancy = aggregated_occupancy,
           @trafficdatadate = [date] 
           FROM dbo.traffic_data_aggregated_hourly    
           WHERE station = @closeststationname  
       AND CONVERT(DATE,[date]) = @accidentdate
       AND period = CASE WHEN SUBSTRING (@accidenttime,1,2) - 1 = -1 THEN 23
                    ELSE SUBSTRING (@accidenttime,1,2) - 1
                    END
       SELECT  @hourlyaggregatedvolume,@hourlyaggregatedspeed,@hourlyaggregatedheadway
       ,@hourlyaggregatedoccupancy,@trafficdatadate
```

Comment: please post Table structure.

Comment: why don't you use datediff provide lil sample data.it is not clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do date maths first, then extract the hour:

```
DATEPART(hour,DATEADD(hour,-1,GETDATE()))
```

(Also, I hate the "short" forms of the date components. I'd always rather spell it out in full e.g. `hour` versus `hh` because I find it more readable, it's usually not much more than a few characters more, and I can never remember which ones are for months vs minutes)

---

References: [`DATEADD`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx), [`DATEPART`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx), [`GETDATE`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx)

Comment: Sorry i cant get this? can you add any example please .

Comment: @bibinmatthew - I'm not sure what else you're looking for. My code is similar to the existing code you had, except it first subtracts one hour from `GETDATE()` and *then* it asks for the `hour` part. If `GETDATE()` returns a value in the range `00.00.00-00.59.59` then the `DATEADD` will first change that to be `23.00.00-23.59.59` of the previous day, and then the `DATEPART()` will extract the correct hour component you wanted.

Comment: @bibinmatthew - if you're wanting more, i.e. this is meant to be part of a larger query, then please edit your question and add some sample data, expected results, etc. You're not going to get a tested query off the back of no information.

Comment: @bibinmatthew: Consider setting up a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/30180) to help explain what you want too.

Comment: @bibinmatthew - yes, it will, for the next ~5 minutes, if you're in a time zone where it's currently 3pm. If you're wanting to remove an hour from any general datetime value or from a column, put that in place of `GETDATE()` - which always returns the current date and time.

Comment: Thanks alot @Damien_The_Unbeliever :) :) well explained :) God bless you bro (y)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```
DECLARE @Now DATETIME = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
DECLARE @FromTimeStamp DATETIME = DATEADD(HOUR, -1, @Now)

SELECT 
    (list of columns)
FROM
    dbo.YourTableNameHere
WHERE
    SomeDateColumn >= @FromTimeStamp
```

or something similar - this selects whatever data columns you want from whatever table you have for the past hour (now minus 1 hour all the way through now).

The `DATEADD` function will handle all the pesky details of date/time math - if you run this 30 minutes after midnight, it **will** handle going back to 11:30pm yesterday just fine.